Extracting (true) marginal effects from nonlinear mixed effects models
I am modelling a binary data set using what I believe should be termed a nonlinear mixed effects model
logit(pi) = mu + beta*x + U_1 + U_2 + U_3
where pi is the probability of event, mu is the overall mean, x is a mode indicator (0 = baseline mode, 1 = comparator mode), and the Us are random effects (independent, normally distributed, mean zero).  Here is my R command using lme4::glmer():
glmer(majorDiscordance ~ 1 + mode + (1|sample) + (1|reader) + (1|site), data = dat, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
The quantity of interest is the difference in probability of event between the two groups (pi_2 - pi_1).  I want a marginal estimate of this quantity.
I have learned form reading about this that there is some confusion of terminology here.  Some people use the term 'marginal' to mean 'for a typical cluster' i.e. with the random effects all set to zero.  This is a fairly simple process that I have been able to achieve using the R function margins::margins_summary().  I think a better term for this would be "conditional average effect".
What I'm talking about is the 'population average' effect, where I believe we need to 'integrate out' the random effects.  I believe the function marginaleffects::comparisons() can do this for linear MEMs, but using it for the above (non-linear) model object returns the warning:
For this model type, "marginaleffects" only takes into account the uncertainty in fixed-effect parameters. You can use the "re.form=NA" argument to acknowledge this explicitly and silence this warning
Does anyone know of an R package that can achieve what I want?

Are these two groups of sites, or two groups determined by binary x?
